# How to select distinct ip for each day

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

I have a table called **logvisit** with fields including **ip (varchar(30))** and **date (datetime)** :

```
ip    date
1.1   2016-08-23 00:05:40
1.1   2016-08-24 00:05:15
1.1   2016-08-24 00:05:20
1.2   2016-08-22 00:01:00
1.2   2016-08-22 00:00:30
1.2   2016-08-23 00:01:00
```

**EDIT** : I want to SELECT all distinct ip by DAY. One IP can have several days (if the user comes three days in a row), and one day can have several IP (because I have more than one user). I just don't want the same IP on the same day.

Expected output (1 ip / 1 day) :

```
ip    day
1.1   2016-08-23
1.1   2016-08-24
1.2   2016-08-22
1.2   2016-08-23
```

I found this thread [SQL group by day, with count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455054/sql-group-by-day-with-count) so as a beginning I tried :

```
SELECT 
  Convert(char(8), date, 112),
  count(distinct ip)
FROM logvisit
GROUP BY Convert(char(8), date, 112)
```

which gave me an unexpected "Syntax error near 112), count(distinct ip"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group by both `ip & date`

```
SELECT 
  DATE(date) AS d,
  count(ip)
FROM logvisit
GROUP BY d,ip
```

**Note:** `Date(time_stamp/datetime)` will extract the date part.

---

If you want to count the distinct ip per day then the following query would be a use :

```
SELECT 
  DATE(date) AS d,
  count(distinct ip) AS dayWiseDistinctIpCount
FROM logvisit
GROUP BY d
```

**EDIT:**

In order to get distinct pair of `<ip,day>` :

```
SELECT 
 DISTINCT ip,
 DATE(date) AS day
FROM logvisit
```

Comment: Sorry, I mislead you. Your answer is syntaxically correct but I have only one IP by day. What I need is ALL distinct ip, for each day, not just one ip for each distinct day (see my edit in post)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ip, DATE(DATE) as day FROM logvisit GROUP BY DATE(DATE),ip
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT id, DATE(`date`) AS day, COUNT(DISTINCT ip) AS total_visits
FROM logvisit
GROUP BY DATE(`date`);
```

Comment: Sorry, I mislead you. Your answer is syntaxically correct but I have only one IP by day. What I need is ALL distinct ip, for each day, not just one ip for each distinct day (see my edit in post)